# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'new'

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am developing a project in python and used mongodb as database. I wanted to create a collection by using pymongo, here is what I have done:

First I created mongodb collection object by:

```
class ReportProblem(Collection):
collection = db.report_problem
report_problem = ReportProblem()
```

And in the python code what I did is :

```
def report_problem():    
   problem_data = dict(
      # Data which needs to be store
)
report_problem.new(**problem_data)
```

So I got an error:

> AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'new'" at line report_problem.new(**problem_data)"

Did anybody know why this is happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`report_problem` is a function, since you used the `def` keyword to define it. Functions don't have a method called `.new()`.

If you defined your `ReportProblem()` instance to a variable named `report_problem` previously, then when you define the function `report_problem`, the instance is *shadowed*